# installing node.js not working

Tags: software-installation, nodejs

I'm trying to install node.js on ubuntu 14.10

I do not want to use the ubuntu package but the latest stable version of node - v0.10.36 so I have installed pvm and have installed node v0.10.36

so far so good, when i run

```
node -v
```

it correctly gives me the right version.

However if I now close the console I did the install from and open a new console, and run node -v again, I get the infamous conflict message -

```
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

If I run nvm install 0.10.36, it tells me it is already installed, but node -v works again

I cannot actually see node in usr\bin

How to I find out where it got installed to and what do I have to do to make node work between console closes?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply by create symbolic link to nodejs:

First check if nodejs exist:
ls -l /usr/bin/nodejs

The create symbolic link:
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

Comment: I don't have a nodejs, node was installed by nvm to .nvm/v0.10.26/bin in my home directory. Do I still set a symbolic link or add the directory to my PATH?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the same error on Ubuntu 14.04 when closing the console.

As seen [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage), once NVM is installed, you have to create a `default` to start with the console :

> To set a default Node version to be used in any new shell, use the
>   alias 'default':
>
> `nvm alias default node`

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with node package in Ubuntu... I saved myself a headache by downloading node zip from the official site and extracted the files to their respective postions.... I.e the files in the extracted bin folder to /usr/bin and the rest respectively